# WPCARGO ERROR Fatal error: Uncaught Picqer

Tags: php, wordpress

Fatal error: Uncaught Picqer\Barcode\Exceptions\BarcodeException: Neither gd-lib or imagick are installed! in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\lib\barcode-generator\vendor\picqer\php-barcode-generator\src\BarcodeGeneratorPNG.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\admin\includes\functions.php(697): Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG->_*construct() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\admin\classes\class-wpcargo.php(111): wpcargo_generate_barcodecode('IMEX084445-AIR') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\classes\class-wpc-shortcode.php(106): WPCargo->barcode_url(110) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WPCargo_Track_Form->wpcargo_trackform_result_header_details_template(Object(stdClass)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\templates\result-form.tpl.php(17): do_action('wpcargo_track_h...', Object(stdClass)) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\classes\class-wpc-shortcode.php(82): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WPCargo_Track_Form->wpcargo_trackform_result_template(10) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\classes\class-wpc-shortcode.php(35): do_action('wpcargo_track_r...', 10) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(395): WPCargo_Track_Form->wpcargo_trackform('', '', 'wpcargo_trackfo...') #13 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(235): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(wpcarg...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[wpcargo_trackf...') #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): do_shortcode('[wpcargo_trackf...') #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('[wpcargo_trackf...', Array) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php(256): apply_filters('the_content', '[wpcargo_trackf...') #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\kadence\template-parts\content\entry_content.php(16): the_content('Continue readin...') #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(787): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(720): load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', false, Array) #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(206): locate_template(Array, true, false, Array) #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\kadence\template-parts\content\single-entry.php(28): get_template_part('template-parts/...', 'page') #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(787): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(720): load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', false, Array) #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(206): locate_template(Array, true, false, Array) #26 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\kadence\inc\template-functions\single-functions.php(27): get_template_part('template-parts/...', 'page') #27 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): Kadence\single_content('') #28 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #29 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #30 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\kadence\template-parts\content\single.php(34): do_action('kadence_single*...') #31 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(787): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #32 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(720): load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', false, Array) #33 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(206): locate_template(Array, true, false, Array) #34 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\kadence\inc\template-functions\single-functions.php(20): get_template_part('template-parts/...', 'page') #35 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): Kadence\single_markup('') #36 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #37 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #38 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\kadence\page.php(20): do_action('kadence_single') #39 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #40 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #41 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #42 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpcargo\lib\barcode-generator\vendor\picqer\php-barcode-generator\src\BarcodeGeneratorPNG.php on line 22

I manot sure what it is

Comment: Seems like an issue with the wpcargo plugin, have you contacted the plugin author about this issue? There is no one better than the official developer for providing help with this issue.
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wpcargo/  

https://www.wpcargo.com/contact-us-2/

Comment: *"Neither gd-lib or imagick are installed"* That explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error and I came up with a solution.

Open this Xampp dashboard, follow these steps
[image]

Then [image]
after that locate this text file.

Uncomment `extension=zip` and `extension=gd` by removing `;` in front of these lines.

After that error has fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In apache php.ini find the `;extension=gd`

Remove the comment sign `;` and then save the file.